# How to call function next() of tRPC middleware when using Passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, trpc.io

I'm having a problem using passport.js to authenticate jwt with tRPC middleware. I tried calling thre next() function in the callback of passport.authenticate function but it doesn't seem to be working and results in the error,

`{"message": "No result from middlewares - did you forget to 'return next()'?", "code": -32603}`

below is my code,

```
const t = initTRPC.create();

const jwtMiddleware = t.middleware(async ({ ctx, next }) =>
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, async (err) => {
    if (err) throw new TRPCError({ code: 'UNAUTHORIZED' });
    // Calling next() here doesn't seem to be working
    return next();
  })(ctx.req, ctx.res, next),
);

const authedProcedure = t.procedure.use(jwtMiddleware);
```

thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: Hi, is it still actual?